# Asp.Net 5. Error referencing .net library on another path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a setup that looks like this

ServiceA\src\aspnetproject

ServiceB\src\aspnetproject

SharedComponents\src\sharedcomponent

Each service has it's own solution file that also includes some of the shared components. The shared components are classic .Net assemblies. The wrap project.json files are located in SharedComponents\src\wrap\sharedcomponent. I can add the reference to the sharedcomponent from the aspnetproject without issues, but using it fails to build. This works fine when the projects are all in the same folder. Any ideas?

Build error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BeoCloud.Core.Models, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: FacadeApiService, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  BeoCloud.Core.Models -> C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Core\src\BeoCloud.Core.Models\bin\Debug\BeoCloud.Core.Models.dll
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Api, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Facade\src\Api\Controllers\SearchController.cs(14,69,14,88): DNX 4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleSearchRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3>C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Facade\src\Api\Controllers\SearchController.cs(14,27,14,47): DNX 4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleSearchResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3>C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Facade\src\Api\Controllers\SearchController.cs(28,28,28,48): DNX 4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleSearchResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3>C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Facade\src\Api\Controllers\SearchController.cs(36,28,36,48): DNX 4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleSearchResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3>C:\Projects\BeoCloud\Facade\src\Api\Controllers\SearchController.cs(14,49,14,68): DNX 4.5.1 warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
3>
3>  Build failed.
3>           1 Warning(s).
3>           4 Error(s).
3>
3>  Time elapsed 00:00:00.0609992
3>
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The build error would be helpful

Comment: I have the same issue, but I get an reference error in the project.json. Means I see the problem directly after setting the reference. In the same folder it works fine. I'll try to find or add an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I have added the build error, it isn't very helpful though. I have already created an issue on github https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1058

Comment: @JuergenGutsch i also got reference errors until i created the wrap project.json files